# Google Sheets, increment cell by month

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet that keeps track of how old accounts are by months. 
Is there a way to have Google Sheets auto update a cell on the 1st of each month?

VG: An account is 78 months old and on Sept 1st it turns 79 months. I want to automatically update it on the 1st of the month so I won't have to manually add 1 to every account age cell.

Comment: Does your dataset include account start date? If it does you can just write a simple formula that calculates on the fly the age using system date.

Comment: Because Google sheets acts almost identically to Excel, people that know Excel and look for the tag might miss this if it were only tagged as Google. Was not a forced tag.

Answer (score 1):

This is for *Excel*:

If the value is **78** on 25 August 2016 and you want the value to increment of the first of each month, then enter:

```
=78+MONTH(TODAY())-MONTH(DATEVALUE("8/25/2016"))+12*(YEAR(TODAY())-YEAR(DATEVALUE("8/25/2016")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your dataset does include an account start date in column A, you can calculate how many whole months are between that date and system date today by using:

`=DATEDIF(A2,TODAY(),"M")`

Tested this in Excel but should work in Google Sheets as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could add another field, and do the calculation from the sheet:

```
[A1]=<start date>
[A2]=datedif(a1,today(),"M")
```

Otherwise, you could use a script to do this once a month, but you would need a list of cells somewhere that need to be updated. I would need to see an example of your spreadsheet layout to give you working code.

The process would be to:

1. set a daily trigger
2. check for the first of the month

   - if it is, go and update all the cells
   - if not, try again tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

This worked out well for me in Google Sheets
`DATEDIF("<MY_STARTING_DATE>", today(), "M")`
example:
`DATEDIF("8/1/2021", today(), "M")`