# COUNTA by month and by exclusion in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, counting, countif, google-sheets-query

***HERE IS A SAMPLE SHEET WITH SOLUTION WORKING:***
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Twc9i7D5rDvT_Q88thrwjV8E58Ja7c-ifdlCZDwu6Ok/edit?usp=sharing

---

I have a Google Sheet where I have registries that come from a Google Forms for some sort of Help Desk registry. I'm trying to make a general report tab where things are count, in total and for the current month.

For example, I'm counting how many entries are classified as 'open' and 'ended'

For the global total of 'open' registries I have:

```
=COUNTA(QUERY(INDIRECT("Responses!$N2:$N"), "where not N contains 'Ended'", 0))
```

And for the closed/ended registries I have:

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("Responses!$N2:$N"),"Ended")
```

That works fine. Column "B" is a timestamp and Column "N" just lists the status as "Ended" or something else. But when I try to count by month it fails. I'm trying to use:

```
    =COUNTA(QUERY(INDIRECT("Responses!$N2:$N"),
    "where not N contains Finalizado'",
    INDIRECT("Responses!$B2:$B"),
    ">"&EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1),INDIRECT("Responses!$B2:$B")," 
    <="&EOMONTH(TODAY(),0))")")
```

Can anyone pinpoint the error in the formula?

I also checked these but still no idea where exactly the error is: ([Google Sheets, increment cell by month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39155145/google-sheets-increment-cell-by-month))
([Sum by month in Google Sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51829902/sum-by-month-in-google-sheet))
([Google Sheets =MONTH works but MONTH in QUERY does not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54878095/google-sheets-month-works-but-month-in-query-does-not))
([Calculate number of rows with current month & year in Google Sheets or Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30188741/calculate-number-of-rows-with-current-month-year-in-google-sheets-or-excel))

Comment: Just to complement this, and based on @player0 answer. To merely count non blank answers in a column based on the current month, the code is: `=COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("Responses!$B2:$B"),"<>",INDIRECT("Responses!$B2:$B"),">"&eomonth(Today(),-1),INDIRECT("Responses!$B2:$B"),"<="&eomonth(Today(),0))`

Comment: Another complement. For exclusion (AKA counting everything that IS NOT something, like when you want 'others'), which is not blank and by the current month, you can use: `=COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("Responses!$G2:G"), "<>Doc",
                    INDIRECT("Responses!$G2:G"), "<>Scaneres",
                    INDIRECT("Responses!$G2:G"), "<>Software",
                    INDIRECT("Responses!F2:F"),"<>"                    ,INDIRECT("Responses!$B2:$B"),">"&EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1),INDIRECT("Responses!$B2:$B"),"<="&EOMONTH(TODAY(),0))
        `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this:

```
=COUNTA(IFERROR(QUERY(INDIRECT("Responses!B2:N"); 
"select N 
 where not lower(N) contains 'finalizado'
   and month (B)+1 = "&MONTH(TODAY()); 0)))
```

Comment: Recently I encountered an error. On all the formulas here (your solution and the ones I added in the comments to the question), they all suddenly began returning "0". I noticed the data has some blank cells in N (It is continuous in B which is the timestamp) but that also existed prior, so I have no idea why the formulas suddenly are not working. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: hard to say like this, I would need to examine the sheet. can you share a copy?

Comment: I added a sample sheet with working solution, although the original sheet still shows error, so I will check  all origin cell to see what is the problem. If it is anything significant I'll add it in this post for complementing it.